# add class if check box is checked and assign a class to it's parent div using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to add a class to a parent div of checked checkboxes, for example on click of button I want to check the checked check boxes inside the corresponding parent div, when there is a checked value, a new class should be added to its parent div.
e.g HTML code is

```
<div class="parent">
    <input type="checkbox" name="a" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="b" />
</div>
<div class="parent">
    <input type="checkbox" name="c" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="d" />
</div>
<button>Add Class to parent div</button>
```

Comment: `$(':checkbox:checked').parent().addClass('my-class')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using [:has()](https://api.jquery.com/has-selector/), from the parents point of view, you can do

```
$('button').click(function(){
    $('.parent:has(:checked)').addClass('my-class');
    $('.parent:not(:has(:checked))').removeClass('my-class');
});
```

```js
$('button').click(function(){
    $('.parent:has(:checked)').addClass('my-class');
    $('.parent:not(:has(:checked))').removeClass('my-class');
});
```

```css
.my-class{
  background:green;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">
    <input type="checkbox" name="a" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="b" />
</div>
<div class="parent">
    <input type="checkbox" name="c" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="d" />
</div>
<button>Toggle Class to parent div</button>
```

Comment: and how could this be done if i uncheck the checboxes then my-class should be removed?